# Cannot do "lvcreate" : "not found: device not cleared” on Centos

Tags: centos, lvm

I have created `volume group`, but when I tried to `lvcreate`, it failed:

```
[root@c7v232 ~]# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_1afe5376c50bb27bdc8a0342a0bfb50b
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  13
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               89.87 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              23007
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0   
  Free  PE / Size       23007 / 89.87 GiB
  VG UUID               JZMo2m-CgAd-iQ3l-sNcp-J0W5-jwfi-058onD

[root@c7v232 ~]# vgs
  VG                                  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
  vg_1afe5376c50bb27bdc8a0342a0bfb50b   1   0   0 wz--n- 89.87g 89.87g
[root@c7v232 ~]# lvs
[root@c7v232 ~]# lvcreate -L 5G -n lv_pao vg_1afe5376c50bb27bdc8a0342a0bfb50b
  /dev/vg_1afe5376c50bb27bdc8a0342a0bfb50b/lv_pao: not found: device not cleared
  Aborting. Failed to wipe start of new LV.
```

I known there is a similar question, but it is debian and I cannot find `udev` in Centos.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I haven't installed `udev` yet. Run `yum install libudev-devel` then it works fine.

I don't know why I have `udevadm` and `lvcreate` even before installing `libudev-devel`

Answer (score 1):

I was testing LVM in a minimal qemu environment (no systemd, no udev), and got this error too.

Expanding on the other answer

> Use "lvcreate -Zn …".

and the proposed solution at the Arch Linux forum [[SOLVED] Can't create new lvm logical volume](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=981109#p981109)

> I couldn't find any relevent errors or debugging info, but I've found a solution.
> Add -Z n to dissable zeroing. Then it just works fine.

---

So adding this option creates the logical volume with a warning

```
# lvcreate --zero n --size 10G --name usr vg0
  WARNING: Logical volume vg0/usr not zeroed.
  Logical volume "usr" created.
```

Option `--zero` is also mentioned at option `--activate`

> The --zero option normally requires the LV to be active.

Using `--activate n` gives the same result

```
# lvcreate --activate n --size 10G --name usr vg0
  WARNING: Logical volume vg0/usr not zeroed.
  Logical volume "usr" created.
```

---

But reading further down to OPTIONS [`--zero`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvcreate.8.html#OPTIONS)

> Warning: trying to mount an unzeroed LV can cause the system to hang.

So activate the volume

```
vgchange -a y
```

create the needed `/dev` nodes

```
vgmknodes
```

and zero manually

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/vg0/usr bs=4k count=1
```

before creating the file system

```
mkfs /dev/vg0/usr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that udev is installed and running, it might just be too slow. Or whatever.

Use "lvcreate -Zn …".

Comment: This gives `Option --zero is unsupported with snapshots.
  Run 'lvcreate --help' for more information. `